# Enumeration bitset with increasing weight. (C++ & Boost::dynamic_bitset)

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, bitset

How to implement the algorithm in C++?
The task such, there is a bitset size N. Need to consistently go through all the bitset overhang k = 1,2, ... l, until the total number of sequences is not equal to M. That is, The result should be an array:

```
0 ... 001
0 ... 010
0 ... 100
...
1 ... 000
0 ... 011
0 ... 101
0 ... 110
....
....
etc
```

With a weight of 1 clear bitwise shift to the left. But how to handle the bitset with weight k = 2,3, ... while maintaining the mass of the algorithm I do not know. please help, can someone faced a similar challenge.
Bitset implemented using boost :: dynamic_bitset. The C++ language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this C code helpful.

The function make_sets generates all bitpatterns of a certain weight, so main calls it multiple times to first generate patterns with 1 set bit, then 2 set bits, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d"
#define BYTETOBINARY(byte)  \
  (byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0) 

/* Make all bitsets with bits_to_add set bits in the least significant num_bits bits 
The most significant bit are taken from high_bits.*/
void make_sets(int high_bits, int bits_to_add, int num_bits) {
    // Recurse on the position of the next set bit
    int i;
    if (bits_to_add) {
        for(i=bits_to_add-1;i<num_bits;i++)
            make_sets(high_bits + (1<<i), bits_to_add-1, i);
    } else {
        printf (BYTETOBINARYPATTERN"\n", BYTETOBINARY(high_bits));
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int M;
    for(M=1;M<=5;M++)
        make_sets(0,M,5);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
00001
00010
00100
01000
10000
00011
00101
00110
01001
01010
01100
10001
10010
10100
11000
00111
01011
01101
01110
10011
10101
10110
11001
11010
11100
01111
10111
11011
11101
11110
11111
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is more for C, but thanks anyway.